# Using VB.Net to deploy an Access database but database does not get deployed

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, deployment, installation

My VB.Net application is using a data bound MS Access database.  This app is going to distributed to multiple co-workers so according to almost every article I've read, I need to include the database in my project so that it will get deployed (copied to the user's local directory) when the Setup.exe is run.  When I publish the project, I see both the Database.employ and the DataSet.xsd.employ files in my Application Files that gets created.  Yet when I run the Setup.exe I get an error message telling me that it can't find the file.  I manually check the Data folder where it's looking and there is nothing in it.  It seems that the files I need to get deployed are not getting so.

Everything I've read so far explains how to deploy the database but I haven't been able to find anything about this error I'm receiving or why the files aren't getting copied to the Data folder.

[image: screenshot of the exact error]

Comment: I've tried including the DB in both the project's root folder and in the bin\debug folder but results are the same.

Comment: That doesnt look like an error from Setup, but from your app.  What is the "data folder".  Likely an issue with paths.  (there is no debug or bin folder when deployed)

Comment: My understanding of the Data folder is the location where the deployed files are supposed to get copied to.  In this case, you can see it as the last folder in the path in the screenshot link.

Comment: One other thing I should mention, regarding the bin\debug folder.  When I created my connection string it notified me that the database was local and asked if I wanted to copy it to the output folder.  When I accept that suggestion is copies it to the bin\debug folder whenever I run it through Studio.

Comment: The database doesn't appear to be getting deployed anywhere on the machine.  I can't find any copies anywhere except in my project folders when I do a search for the filename.

Comment: From the path, it looks like you are using ClickOnce to deploy?  On the project properties Publish tab, in Application Files... what is the Publish Status for the database file?  It should probably be Data File if you are expecting it to be in the Data directory.  I think that the default used depends on the build action.

Comment: The connectionstring used in the code would be informative too

Comment: Wow!  That was all I needed to do was change the Publish Status to Datafile.  Thank you so much.

Comment: You should accept Mark's answer. This question is a pretty typical thing newbies miss and it would be nice if the question was made more generic and the answer more informative. Still good stuff nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using ClickOnce to deploy, in order for files to be deployed into the Data directory the Publish Status for the file should be set to Data File on the project properties Publish tab -> Application Files...

Comment: but how do I add a file to that list of files?

Comment: The build action needs to be set to "Content" for the file you want to include.